# SQLCMD Mode run with .net windows application

Tags: .net, sql-server, windows, sqlcmd

I want to run SQLCMD.EXE through .net windows application how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to have to use `ProcessStartInfo` under `using System.Diagnostics;`

```
// Calls the sqlcmd
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo("sqlcmd", @" -S .\sqlexpress -i C:\YourFileName.sql");

//  Indicades if the Operative System shell is used, in this case it is not
info.UseShellExecute = false;

//No new window is required
info.CreateNoWindow = true;

//The windows style will be hidden
info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

//The output will be read by the starndar output process
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process proc = new Process();

proc.StartInfo = info;

//Start the process
proc.Start();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to pass parameter (when call SQLCMD call) in that. so, Pass as argument in process Info?